# React Hook Form - Yup resolver with dynamic field names

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a form in which the input field names are based off of GUIDs. For example, a radio button group may simply be named "6c6f1869-73ae-447b-b893-a089db54d057". This is because my form is dynamically generated by backend schemas which supply the unique identifier for each question that is asked.

```
{props.options.map(option => (
    <input
        type="radio"
        value={option.guid}
        {...register(props.guid)}
)}
```

Therefore, I'm expecting that when I submit the data for this form, React Hook Form's submit data would show something like:

```
{
    6c6f1869-73ae-447b-b893-a089db54d057: 'c2f7ae0d-0f1b-474b-a98a-2c54e17670b9'
}
```

But how would I use a Yup resolver validation schema with a form built in this way? I know that I can put some validation code along with the register function but what if I have some complex form controls whose validation is equally as complex?

The problem that I'm facing is that if I try to put a resolve when I initially create the form:

```
useForm({ resolver: yup.object({ ... }) })
```

I don't know what to put in yup.object since I'd have to know those dynamic guids ahead of time which I don't.

A lot of tutorials just show simple cases in which inputs are named things like "email" or "age" which doesn't exactly help me.